# How to achieve a hairy rendering effect?like Animal Crossing

Tags: unity-game-engine, shader

[hairy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Exvrr.png)

[hairy2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lo69q.jpg)

You can see that the hat and owl are hairy. What method should I use to achieve this effect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's two answers to this:

1. Learn to code shaders if you haven't already. This isn't a trivial problem so you'll need pretty advanced shader coding skills.
2. Go to Unity Asset Store and search for "Fur Shader". None are free and I can't speak for the quality of any of them but this would be my recommended route.